# Select certain keys from array of objects

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, select

Say I have a JSON column `foo` where each value is an array of objects, i.e:

```
[{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue, "othervaluesidontneed":...},
{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue, "othervaluesidontneed":...},
{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue, "othervaluesidontneed":...},...]
```

I want to select this column but for each row, to only include the keys `date` and `value`, so the returned value is:

```
[{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue},
{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue},
{"date": somedate, "value": somevalue},...]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to use `json_table()` (available in MySQ 8.0 only) to expand the array as a set of rows, and then generate a new array of objects that contain only the requested keys with `json_arrayagg()`:

```
select 
    json_arrayagg(json_object( 'date', tt.date, 'value', tt.value)) new_js
from 
    mytable t,
    json_table(
        js,
        "$[*]"
        columns(
            date datetime path "$.date",
            value int path "$.value"
        )
    ) as tt
group by t.id
```

This requires that some column can be used to uniquely identify a row in the initial table: I called that column `id`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e194d37a622941981e8be0ca366cc593)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 1 id, '[
        { "date": "2019-01-01", "value": 1, "othervaluesidontneed": 12 },
        { "date": "2019-01-02", "value": 2, "othervaluesidontneed": 55 },
        { "date": "2019-01-03", "value": 3, "othervaluesidontneed": 72}
    ]' js
)
select 
    json_arrayagg(json_object( 'date', tt.date, 'value', tt.value)) new_js
from 
    mytable t,
    json_table(
        js,
        "$[*]"
        columns(
            date datetime path "$.date",
            value int path "$.value"
        )
    ) as tt
group by t.id
```

```
| new_js                                                                                                                                                       |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| [{"date": "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000", "value": 1}, {"date": "2019-01-02 00:00:00.000000", "value": 2}, {"date": "2019-01-03 00:00:00.000000", "value": 3}] |
```

Comment: `JSON_TABLE` is only available in MySQL 8+

Comment: @Nick: indeed. I just edited my answer to mention this. OP did not state which MySQL version they are using.

Comment: Agreed - so it just needed saying that it was an 8+ function since they may have 5.7 which does have limited JSON support. Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: Thank you, I am stuck on 5.7 unfortunately. Although I appreciate the detailed answer and will accept your answer should no one else respond!